# Error: index 255 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2 error in preprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am applying the semantic segmentation and encounter the problem "index 255 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2 error in preprocessing" I have two class, building class and background.
While running the "x, y = train_img_gen.**next**()" it throws me this error.
Can anybody help me. I have tried few things but nothing is working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqyWj.jpg)

"""

```
Define Generator for images and masks so we can read them directly from the drive. 

seed=24
batch_size= 16
n_classes=2

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

#Use this to preprocess input for transfer learning
BACKBONE = 'resnet34'
preprocess_input = sm.get_preprocessing(BACKBONE)


def preprocess_data(img, mask, num_class):
    img = scaler.fit_transform(img.reshape(-1, img.shape[-1])).reshape(img.shape)
    img = preprocess_input(img)  
    mask = to_categorical(mask, num_class)
      
    return (img,mask)

#Define the generator.
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
def trainGenerator(train_img_path, train_mask_path, num_class):
    
    img_data_gen_args = dict(horizontal_flip=True,
                      vertical_flip=True,
                      fill_mode='reflect')
    
    image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**img_data_gen_args)
    mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**img_data_gen_args)
    
    image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_img_path,
        class_mode = None,
        batch_size = batch_size,
        seed = seed)
    
    mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_mask_path,
        class_mode = None,
        color_mode = 'grayscale',
        batch_size = batch_size,
        seed = seed)
    
    train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
    
    for (img, mask) in train_generator:
        img, mask = preprocess_data(img, mask, num_class)
        yield (img, mask)

train_img_path = "/content/AerialImageDataset/train/data_for_training_and_testing/train_images/"
train_mask_path = "/content/AerialImageDataset/train/data_for_training_and_testing/train_masks/"
train_img_gen = trainGenerator(train_img_path, train_mask_path, num_class=2)

val_img_path = "/content/AerialImageDataset/train/data_for_training_and_testing/val_images/"
val_mask_path = "/content/AerialImageDataset/train/data_for_training_and_testing/val_masks/"
val_img_gen = trainGenerator(val_img_path, val_mask_path, num_class=2)

x, y = train_img_gen.__next__()
```

"""

Comment: The error message shows that you are trying to reshape a vector into an array with size (-1, 256). I think you meant to resize the image, you might want to consider using `tf.image.resize` instead.

Comment: For future reference, please share the error message in text rather than a screenshot. Folks will be inclined to ignore questions that need additional effort to read.